# Grouping object by date and sum-ing value in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects where each object has a string and a int. Each string is a date in the yyyy-M-d format.

The list can contain dates 30, 90 or 365 days from the first date

So a list of items (of 30 days) would be:

```
2017-7-25  10
2017-7-24  3
2017-7-23  7
2017-7-22  4
2017-7-21  2
2017-7-20  4
..
2017-6-27  5
2017-6-26  8
```

I want to group these dates by 5 days such that:

```
2017-7-21 30
2017-7-16 (Sum of values from 7-16 till 7-20)
```

and so on.

I cant figure out the lambda for this.

```
var grouped = from x in list 
              group x by DateTime.Parse(x.date)/5
              select new { date = x.????????, count  = x.Sum()}
```

Comment: Are the days unique?

Comment: @Christos Yes, the days are unique. I corrected the mistake I made in the list in the question. 

The list is basically every day from now going back 30 or 90 or 365 days and a value for each day (which can be 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have declared a class like the following:

```
internal class DayNumber
{
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

and you have defined a list like the following one:

```
var list = new List<DayNumber>
{
    new DayNumber {Day = "2017-7-25", Number = 10},
    new DayNumber {Day = "2017-7-24", Number = 3},
    new DayNumber {Day = "2017-7-23", Number = 7},
    new DayNumber {Day = "2017-7-22", Number = 4},
    new DayNumber {Day = "2017-7-21", Number = 2},
    new DayNumber {Day = "2017-7-20", Number = 4},
    new DayNumber {Day = "2017-7-19", Number = 5},
    new DayNumber {Day = "2017-7-18", Number = 8},
    new DayNumber {Day = "2017-7-17", Number = 2},
    new DayNumber {Day = "2017-7-16", Number = 3}
};
```

then you could try something like this:

```
var grouped = list.Select(item => new 
                  {
                      Parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(item.Day, "yyyy-M-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
                      Number = item.Number
                  })
                  .OrderBy(item => item.Parsed)
                  .Select((item, index) => new 
                  {
                      Index = index, 
                      Item = item
                  })
                  .GroupBy(item => item.Index / 5)
                  .Select(gr => new 
                  {
                      Date = gr.First().Item.Parsed, 
                      Count = gr.Sum(x => x.Item.Number)
                  })
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: As far as I understand this works only if days are consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

This will works regardless of date uniqueness and gaps between dates.

---

Assuming we have class representing your object

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string DateString { get; set; }

    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}
```

then we have array of this objects

```
MyClass[] array = new[]
{
    new MyClass { DateString = "2017-7-25", SomeInt = 10 },
    new MyClass { DateString = "2017-7-24", SomeInt = 3 },
    new MyClass { DateString = "2017-7-23", SomeInt = 7 },
    new MyClass { DateString = "2017-7-22", SomeInt = 4 },
    new MyClass { DateString = "2017-7-21", SomeInt = 2 },
    new MyClass { DateString = "2017-7-20", SomeInt = 4 },
    new MyClass { DateString = "2017-7-25", SomeInt = 5 },
    new MyClass { DateString = "2017-6-26", SomeInt = 8 }
};
```

In this case code will be

```
// get object array with parsed dates
var arrayWithDates = array.Select(el => 
    new
    {
        Date = DateTime.ParseExact(el.DateString, "yyyy-M-d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        SomeInt = el.SomeInt
    });

// get minimum date
DateTime minDate = arrayWithDates.Min(el => el.Date);

// get maximum date
DateTime maxDate = arrayWithDates.Max(el => el.Date);

// get total days
int days = (maxDate - minDate).Days;

// getting all dates from minDate to maxDate
IEnumerable<DateTime> dateRange = Enumerable.Range(0, days + 1)
    .Select(el => minDate.AddDays(el));

// split all dates into groups of 5 dates
IEnumerable<DateTime[]> groupedDateRanges = dateRange
    .Select((el, index) => new { el.Date, index })
    .GroupBy(el => el.index / 5)
    .Select(g => g.Select(el => el.Date).ToArray());

var results = groupedDateRanges
    // getting list of object within each range
    .Select(groupedDateRange => arrayWithDates.Where(el => groupedDateRange.Contains(el.Date)))
    // selecting minimum date of range, maximum date of range and sum by int value
    .Select(item =>
        new
        {
            MinDate = item.Min(el => el.Date),
            MaxDate = item.Max(el => el.Date),
            Sum = item.Sum(el => el.SomeInt)
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
            KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, int>();
            IList < KeyValuePair < string, int> >  list= new 
            List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("2017 - 7 - 25", 10));
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("2017 - 7 - 24", 3));
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("2017 - 7 - 23", 7));
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("2017 - 7 - 22", 4));
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("2017 - 7 - 21", 2));
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("2017 - 7 - 25", 5));
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("2017 - 6 - 26", 8));
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("2017 - 5 - 26", 18));


            TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(5);     
            var output=list.GroupBy(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Key).Ticks / interval.Ticks)
            .Select((n) => new { GroupId = new DateTime(n.Key * interval.Ticks), Sum= n.Sum(x => x.Value) })
```